# Twitter api call no longer working after uploading Flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, twitter

I have a Flex application that uses the Last.fm and Twitter api. After I uploaded the project to my webspace, the Twitter api call doesn't work anymore, but the Last.fm still works. My url still works:

```
var getTweetsUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=deftonesband&count=3"
```

This is the code used for the httpservice:

```
    <s:HTTPService id="getTweetsService" url="{getTweetsUrl}" result="displayTweets(event)" fault="twitterFail(event)" resultFormat="e4x" />
```

Every time the fault event is fired, even though the url is correct. Anyone knows of this problem?

Comment: I think you need to have an application key from Twitter that allows you to consume their service.  You may not need so when the application (in your case, Flash) is running locally, but the key is necessary for any hosted application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to crossdomain policy of twitter.com (https://api.twitter.com/crossdomain.xml) you are not able to invoke twitter api from other domain without permission  (locally there is no crossdomain check in flash player)

to get permission from twitter user you have to use [oAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

I think easiest way to implement oAuth for twitter api is to use Open Source library for AS3 called Tweetr:
http://wiki.swfjunkie.com/tweetr

Comment: Does this also mean that users will have to login with their Twitter account or not? Thanks.

Comment: yes, have to login with their twitter account and give permission to your application